# to much value element in linked list C/C++

Tags: c, linked-list

I want put value in linked list. But I have a problem, becouse I want get this:
123
but I get this
123
123
123
.
.
to infinity. What I doing wrong ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct lista{
    int data;
    struct lista *next;
    struct lista *prev;
};

struct lista *push(struct lista *head, struct lista *x){
    x->next = head;
    x->prev = NULL;
    if(head!=NULL)
        head->prev=x;
    return x;
}

void show(struct lista *head){
    while(head!=NULL){
        printf("%d\n", head->data);
        }
    head = head->next;
}

int main(){
    struct lista *head = NULL, *x = NULL;
    x = (struct lista*)malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
    x->data = 123;
    head = push(head, x);
    show(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [tutorial](https://pastebin.com/HC1DLK4M)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you made *slight* but *sevior* mistake of "**infinity loop**".

**Always notice 2 key points in the infinity case :-**
**Point 1**. "Condition" on the Control variable (i.e. *head) loop must be proper enough.
**Point 2**. "Updation" on Control variable must be given to reach the end point of loop from the initialization of control var.

okey, now you wouldn't be confuse in this problem to find the solution by self. :)

**So, now you're able to troubleshoot and testing of problem.**

```
void show(struct lista *head){                   
    while(head!=NULL){  //1.Condtion on *head look might be proper 
        printf("%d\n", head->data);
        }
    head = head->next;  //2. update on *head out of loop which gives *infininty*

}
```

Solution:-

```
void show(struct lista *head){                   
    while(head!=NULL){                
        printf("%d\n", head->data);
        head = head->next;  //now the update work in loop *to break infinity*
    }
}
```

Comment: Indentation is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Change this :

```
void show(struct lista *head){
    while(head!=NULL){
        printf("%d\n", head->data);
    }
    head = head->next;
}
```

to :

```
void show(struct lista *head){
    lista *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL){
        printf("%d\n", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

---

***Reason for this modification :***

You change `head` pointer *outside* the `while` loop, so `head` will always be the same. In your case it is not `NULL` so it will infinitely be printing the `data` in the node that `head` currently shows.

Also, it is better to not modify the `head` of your list directly, because you will not be able to access it again.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change the show method the following way and not change the head;

```
void show(struct lista *head){
    lista *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL){
        printf("%d\n", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    //head = head->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In show(), just move the line to advance head to within the while loop:

```
void show(struct lista *head){
    while(head!=NULL){
        printf("%d\n", head->data);
        head = head->next;     /* moved this line */
    }                          /*  usual indentation for } */
}
```

C function calls pass parameters by value (not by reference), so the show function will not modify the value of head in main() when it calls show().

Shivam Sharma appears to have answered before I did, although my edit may have changed the order of answers. He should get the "check" for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your increment to the pointer `head` is outside the loop so actually `head` never changes and so it keeps on printing same value.

Change your method `show` to the following:

```
void show(struct lista *head){
    while(head!=NULL){
        printf("%d\n", head->data);
        head = head->next;
        }

}
```

Now after each `printf` statement your pointer `head` is moving to the next element of the list and thus it will work as expected.